# Анимация слоя по мере продвижения ListView

Tags: android, listview, анимация, android-layout

Задача: при приближении к последнему элементу ListView, начать анимацию include (сдвиг вверх) по мере продвижении в ListView.

Не нашел ничего на эту тему. Да и вообще на тему анимации не так много материала. Может, подскажите какой-нибудь ресурс, если таковой существует?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вам лучше использовать ReyclerView, ибо ListView уже устарел и имеет ряд недостатков относительно RecyclerView.

Вот статьи, где описывают как работать с анимацией и ReyclerView.

https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213

https://androidexample365.com/an-android-animation-library-which-easily-add-itemanimator-to-recyclerview-items/

Далее, вы можете посмотреть на библиотеки и если вы найдете решение, то воспользоваться ими. Или же углубитесь в изучение кода и модернизируйте под свои нужды.

Вот примеры библиотек:

https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView

Comment: Анимация нужна не для RecycleView, а для include (FrameLayout включающий Button и TextView)